# Pode ocorrer do Entity Framework não mapear uma tabela no MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Adicionei uma tabela nova no Model.edmx, mais não foi criado no Model.Context.cs o

```
public DbSet<informacoes> informacoes { get; set; }
```

é também não foi criado no Model.tt a classe desta tabela.
como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clica com o botão direito sobre o `Model.tt` e ache a opção `Run custom tool`:

[image: Menu <code>run custom tool</code>]